# Total Number count of fields on a Page Layout

Tags: page-layout

I am trying to do analysis on the number of fields comparing 2 different page layouts and Could not find an easy way to count the number of fields added to a page layout.  Would anyone be able to assist me?  I attempted to copy all of the fields and paste it into notepad which didnt work well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [describeLayout()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout.htm) API method to pull details about the page layouts for an object.

Drill down into the returned [DescribeLayoutResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout_describelayoutresult.htm) to find the DescribeLayoutComponents with the LayoutComponentType/type of Field. The value will be the name of the field being used on the page layout.

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to load up your project in the Force.com IDE, making sure that you select Layouts in the metadata when creating a project:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

Once your project is created select both layout files, right click and Compare To each other to get a diff between the two files.